# NullReferenceException shown every single time a change is applied to my prefab

Tags: unity

I created a prefab out of a game object in my scene. Every single time I hit `Apply` after making changes to my game object, I see the following stack trace:

[image]

However, as far as I can surmise, the changes are applied nonetheless, because the bolded field (indicating that its value is yet to be applied to the prefab) immediately becomes un-bolded once I hit `Apply`.

1. If, contrary to my belief, my changes are not applied to my prefab, what should I do to ensure that they are?
2. If the error message appears even when I successfully apply my changes to my prefab, what can I do to make it go away?

**UPDATE 1:**

I noticed that after the first time I hit `Apply`, the game object went from being highlighted in blue (indicating that it mirrors a prefab) to being highlighted in black (indicating that it no longer mirrors a prefab).

Game objects that mirror other prefabs work fine. This is the only exception.

**UPDATE 2:**

I deleted the prefab, and created another prefab from the same game object. This time, after hitting `Apply`, I still see the same exception, but the game object remains highlighted in blue (indicating that it is still mirroring a prefab).

Comment: I've been getting a few random but so-far-seemingly-harmless errors & exceptions from Unity's internal editor processes in 2017 versions, though I have not observed this one in particular. It's likely a case to log as a bug, especially if you can narrow down the steps to reproduce it. Does it occur with every prefab (say, create a default cube and make a prefab of that) or only ones with particular scripts/assets in use?

Comment: @DMGregory I have updated my post with more details.

Comment: Cool. Try making a copy of the object, and change one thing about it — like remove a particular component. Then prefab that, and see if it exhibits the same problem. Or try rebuilding a similar object from scratch and try prefabbing it. Keep tweaking & checking the prefab behaviour to see if you can isolate what it is about this object that's triggering the error. Maybe try saving the prefab to different names/folders too.

Comment: @DMGregory I made another update -- please read and let me know if the situation rings a bell...

Comment: You don't need to @ me with each discovery. ;) Keep trying different variations until you have what's called a minimal complete verifiable example: a set of instructions you could hand to someone that would let them reproduce this error.

Comment: @DMGregory The error occurs only with that game object with all its children and nested children. Once I delete one of its children -- any children -- and create a prefab from it, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to resolve the issue:

I deleted the game object from the scene, along with its prefab. I checked my changes into source control.

I asked my game designer to add the game object back into the scene, and then to check in his change.

I pulled his change, and re-created a prefab from the game object. Everything started working as expected -- I no longer see the error message, and all changes I make to the game object are now correctly applied to the prefab as well.

I still don't understand what happened in the first place to cause the problem, but the aforementioned approach fixed it.